# is this the correct universal property of free Lie superalgebras?

Tags: lie-superalgebras, free-lie-algebras

Consider a $\Bbb Z_2$ graded set $A$.

Universal property of free Lie superalgebra $FLS(A)$: Let $\mathfrak g$ be a Lie superalgebra and let $\Phi: A \to \mathfrak g$ be a set map which preserves the $\mathbb Z_2$ grading. Then $\Phi$ can be extended to a Lie superalgebra homomorphism $\Phi: FLS(A) \to \mathfrak g$.

My questions.

1. Is this the correct universal property of free Lie superalgebras?
2. Why do we need the set map to preserve the $\Bbb Z_2$ grading?
3. What is the definition of Lie sub-superalgebra generated by a set $S$ where $S$ is a subset of $FLS(A)$?
4. More generally, if $\mathfrak g = \frac{FLS(A)}{R}$ then the Lie sub-superalgebra generated by $S$ in $\mathfrak g$ is equal to $\mathfrak g = \frac{FLS(S)}{R}$ where $s$ is a subset of $\mathfrak g$?

Thank you.